# OHS and ProxyPass and RewriteRule / RedirectMatch

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, http, oracle, proxypass

i've setted up this virtualhost,

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName test.domain.org
      DocumentRoot "/u02/config/www/tst-12c"
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(OPTIONS)
      RewriteRule .* - [F]
      RewriteEngine On
       
      RedirectMatch ^/ui/#/project/([^/]+)$ /ui-v2/#/project/$1

      #  SSL Engine Switch:
      #  Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
      SSLEngine on

       <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
          SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
       </FilesMatch>

       <Directory "${ORACLE_INSTANCE}/config/fmwconfig/components/${COMPONENT_TYPE}/instances/${COMPONENT_NAME}/cgi-bin">
          SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
       </Directory>

       <Directory "/u02/config/www/tst-12c/">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride ALL
          Require all granted
       </Directory>

       BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
       nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
       downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
      
       <Proxy "balancer://api_cluster">
            BalancerMember "http://realbackend_server1:9006/api"
            BalancerMember "http://realbackend_server1:9006/api"
       </Proxy>
       ProxyPass "/api" "balancer://api_cluster"
       ProxyTimeout 240
```

but the RedirectMatch rule is not working , i've enabled the debug mode, and i see all is being redirected to /api which the RedirectMatch does the comparison to.

in the debug files i see messages like :

AH00947: connected /api/virtualassistant/RG1080A-02 to **realbackend_server1:9006**, referer https://test.domain.org/ui/

RewriteCond: input='/api/virtualassistant/RG1080A-02' pattern='^/ui/#/project/([^/]+)' [NC] => not-matched, referer https://test.domain.org/ui/

which means the RedirectMatch is working , but being executed after the ProxyPass is done, rather than before. i've tried RewriteRule too, but it does the same.

any clue why this is happening and how can i solve it?

regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About mod\_rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)